# Conversion of Java to C# code

Tags: java, c#, arrays, final

All,

I am currently trying to convert some lines of code from Java to C# using Visual Studio 2013. However the lines below is causing me some issues:

```
final double testdata[][] = {{patientTemperatureDouble, heartRateDouble, coughInteger, skinInteger}};
result[i] = BayesClassifier.CalculateProbability{testdata[k],category[i]};
```

Any clarification as to converting the array to a suitable c# format would be greatly appreciated, I have attempted using readonly and sealed but I've had no luck.

Thanks

Comment: "some issues" is not a description of what problem you are having

Comment: @khelwood, cheers mate, so helpful. The issues its having is that I cannot convert the array to a runnable C# format as I said in the question.

Comment: @GlenThomas thanks for your help, much better than the other guy

Comment: @J.Doe what the scope of your testdata? variable in a method? or a class' field?

Comment: J. , I guess @khelwood did not mean to be rude. People new to SO sometimes describe their problems as "does not work" or "having an issue" which does not leave much information for others to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As asked in the comment, if your `testdata` is a class' field, you could use `readonly` keyword. **But if it is a local variable/method parameter, there is no direct equivalent in C#**. In either case, given a set of `double[]`, you can initialize a `double[][]` jagged array by removing one of the curly brackets:

```
readonly double[][] testdata = new double[][] { //for class field
    patientTemperatureDouble, //is double[]
    heartRateDouble, //is double[]
    coughInteger, //is double[]
    skinInteger //is double[]
};

double[][] testdata = new double[][] { //for local variable
    patientTemperatureDouble, //is double[]
    heartRateDouble, //is double[]
    coughInteger, //is double[]
    skinInteger //is double[]
};
```